# Common name for the formula $\sum_{i=0}^n k^i = \frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Recently I had been looking for an explicit formula for the sum $$\sum_{i=0}^n k^i$$
I recalled the formula that we saw in highschool, which is $$\frac{k^{n+1}-1}{k-1}$$
However, I realized that I have no idea on by what name it goes on the internet or textbooks when it is referred to. I needed that to see a few ideas on it's derivation. Though as I stated, I don't know how to refer to it and google hasn't been helpful with leading me to the right results.

I've even searched for an example query of $S_1, S_2, S_3, S_4, S_5$ for $Sn = \sum_{i=0}^n 3^i$, and that is $1, 4, 13, 40, 121$ on OEIS (On-line Enclopedia of Integer Sequences), but couldn't go nowhere from there.

Anyways, to cut short, does this explicit formula has a name such as *Sum of powers of a number* or "Bernoulli's sequence partial sum"* or such? or are there any sources that you would recommend me to check out to reach more information about the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more commonly known as a geometric series, where series means "sum of a sequence".

Answer (score 2):

It's called the sum of a geometric sequence.